# Layout with invisible button steals click events from underlying button in Qt5 form (QtCreator)

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt5, qt-creator

I have designed a form in **QtCreator** for **Qt5** where I have a row of buttons without layout (*Blueberry+*, *Peach*, *Lemon*, *Mango* and *Water* in screenshot below) with a grid layout on top.

The grid layout has one button (*Register Now*), one label(*HELLO JOHN*) and two horizontal spacers inside:

[image: Screenshot of layout in QtCreator]

In the code, the label and button in the layout are set to **visible=false**.

When I start the program and show the screen I only see the underlying row of buttons, but I can't click them. The layout seems to somehow steal the focus. I can verify this by moving the layout in the editor to see the boundary for where my clicks work following it.

Other than this there isn't much going on in the gui, so I am kind of stumped as to why a QGridLayout steals my clicks.

Any tips on how I can avoid this?

Comment: does my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

**You should hide the QGridLayout itself and not the button and label.**

You are done here if the button and label hides and shows togather.

if not. along with showing and hidding the grid. show and hide the label and button.

Does that seems to solve the problem?

Comment: I removed the grid and recreated it. Now it is the other way arround (register button does not receive clicks) even if it is topmost. And to commend on your answer, unfortunately the main reason for making the layout in the first place was to make sure the button and label aligned well even when only one was removed. I will test anyways.

Comment: BTW: there is no setVisible() on layout, only setEnabled() which simply stops the layout from working but does not hide anything.